# Remove spaces into a file in the middle of a text android

Tags: android, android-file

In the below code I tried to remove the spaces from the text when I am reading the file but it doesn't remove all spaces between the text. Below is my code. I have used trim() function as well but again in the middle, there are some spaces.

```
try {
    fis = openFileInput("testlab.txt");
    DataInputStream dataIO = new DataInputStream(fis);
    String strLine = null;

    if ((strLine = dataIO.readLine()) != null) {
        storedString.append(strLine);
        String all = storedString.toString();
      all=all.trim();
       Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(all);

       boolean checking = matcher.find();
       check=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

      all = matcher.replaceAll(" ");



        String alll [] = all.split(" ###");

       for(int k = 0; k < alll.length; k++){
             urls_and_desc = alll[k].split("##");
           HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
           map.put("name", urls_and_desc[0].toString());
           map.put("spinn", urls_and_desc[1].toString());
           map.put("price", urls_and_desc[2].toString());

           productsList.add(map);
        String f = urls_and_desc[2].toString();
     wholeshop = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalprice2);
        b= b + Double.parseDouble(f);


        wholeshop.setText(Double.toString(b));
       }



    }


}
catch  (Exception e) {  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just use replace() once you have readed the file into a string?

```
String resultString = originString.replace(" ","");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: because it is not just a double space sometimes more than double, also I tried this one but again spaces is not removed.

Comment: That should remove every " " character, why it isnt working?